# Trying to sort values in alphabetical order for dictionary in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

```
mapping = defaultdict(list)

betterMap = {}

with open ('pokemonResult.csv') as pokeMon: # Open file
    
    reader = csv.reader(pokeMon)
    
    next(reader)
    
    for num,row in enumerate(reader): # Map personality as value with type as the key
        mapping[row[4]].append(row[3])
        
    for key, value in mapping.items(): # Duplicate to other dictionary
        betterMap[key] = set(value)
        
    print(sorted(betterMap.items())) # This method will sort the keys in proper order
    print(sorted(betterMap.values())) # Tried to test this, but to no avail
    
    f1 = open("pokemon4.txt", "w")
    f1.write() # Will be written when the problem is sorted
    f1.close()
```

I'm trying to read a csv file full of pokemon stats and want to make a dictionary where the keys are the pokemon types and the values are the personalities mapped to the types. The problem I'm having is that I want to sort the keys and values in alphabetical order. With the current code I have, I get this result...

```
[('bug', {'careful'}), ('electric', {'hardy'}), ('fairy', {'naughty', 'impish', 'sassy'}), ('fighting', {'adamant', 'serious', 'careful', 'lonely', 'hasty'}), ('fire', {'gentle', 'impish', 'bold', 'rash', 'naughty', 'lax', 'docile', 'bashful', 'modest', 'hardy', 'timid', 'jolly', 'brave'}), ('flying', {'impish'}), ('grass', {'gentle', 'impish', 'bold', 'rash', 'adamant', 'sassy', 'quiet', 'naive', 'bashful', 'docile', 'calm', 'lonely', 'mild'}), ('ground', {'gentle', 'hardy', 'bashful', 'quiet'}), ('normal', {'naughty', 'lax', 'quiet', 'serious', 'relaxed', 'jolly', 'calm', 'brave', 'mild'}), ('rock', {'impish', 'naughty', 'docile', 'bashful', 'mild'}), ('water', {'hardy'})]
```

The keys are sorted just how I want them, but I want the values to be sorted as well. Is there some way I can do this?

Comment: This is not a dictionary, but a list of tuples. Also, you've put the values in a set, which is an unordered data type in Python. Use a list instead, if order matters. There are ordered set recipes as well, but you likely don't need it to be a set?

Comment: you will have to use `[value]` instead of `set(value)` to keep orders. And you have to run for-loop to sort in every `[value]` separatelly. So maybe use `betterMap[key] = list(sorted(value))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep order you have to use `list` instead of `set()` and you have to sort every list separatelly.

But you have to remeber that `dictionary` doesn't have to keep order - in newest Python it tries to keep order but in older Python version it doesn't have to but it has `collections.OrderedDict()` for this.

```
data = [('bug', {'careful'}), ('electric', {'hardy'}), ('fairy', {'naughty', 'impish', 'sassy'}), ('fighting', {'adamant', 'serious', 'careful', 'lonely', 'hasty'}), ('fire', {'gentle', 'impish', 'bold', 'rash', 'naughty', 'lax', 'docile', 'bashful', 'modest', 'hardy', 'timid', 'jolly', 'brave'}), ('flying', {'impish'}), ('grass', {'gentle', 'impish', 'bold', 'rash', 'adamant', 'sassy', 'quiet', 'naive', 'bashful', 'docile', 'calm', 'lonely', 'mild'}), ('ground', {'gentle', 'hardy', 'bashful', 'quiet'}), ('normal', {'naughty', 'lax', 'quiet', 'serious', 'relaxed', 'jolly', 'calm', 'brave', 'mild'}), ('rock', {'impish', 'naughty', 'docile', 'bashful', 'mild'}), ('water', {'hardy'})]

data = dict(data)

#new_data = dict()

import collections
new_data = collections.OrderedDict()

for key in sorted(data.keys()):
    new_data[key] = list(sorted(data[key]))

for item in new_data.items():
    print(item)
```

Result:

```
('bug', ['careful'])
('electric', ['hardy'])
('fairy', ['impish', 'naughty', 'sassy'])
('fighting', ['adamant', 'careful', 'hasty', 'lonely', 'serious'])
('fire', ['bashful', 'bold', 'brave', 'docile', 'gentle', 'hardy', 'impish', 'jolly', 'lax', 'modest', 'naughty', 'rash', 'timid'])
('flying', ['impish'])
('grass', ['adamant', 'bashful', 'bold', 'calm', 'docile', 'gentle', 'impish', 'lonely', 'mild', 'naive', 'quiet', 'rash', 'sassy'])
('ground', ['bashful', 'gentle', 'hardy', 'quiet'])
('normal', ['brave', 'calm', 'jolly', 'lax', 'mild', 'naughty', 'quiet', 'relaxed', 'serious'])
('rock', ['bashful', 'docile', 'impish', 'mild', 'naughty'])
('water', ['hardy'])
```